# In Css, how to select class of a span tag which parent is a div with class "X"?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am dealing with a complicated problem, indeed I want to change the css on this piece of code:

```
<div class="et_pb_module et-waypoint et_pb_image et_pb_animation_left circular et_pb_image_2 et_always_center_on_mobile et_pb_has_overlay">
<a href="https:/....ee/?page_id=460"><img src="https://..../wp-content/uploads/2017/00565531_813167153_o.jpg" alt="" />
<span class="et_overlay"></span></a>
</div>
```

I need to change the `et_overlay` class and I want especially to change this class for `span` tag which parent is a `div` with the `circular` class, which is the case in this piece of code. (some other parts of the code has the same configuration but without the class `circular` and I don't want to change those parts)

I have checked the different CSS selectors but I could not find any selector that fits my needs.

Any idea ?

Much thanks

Comment: `DIV.circular > span.et_overlay`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.circular span.et_overlay` (note the *space*) - see demo below:

```css
.circular span.et_overlay {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="et_pb_module et-waypoint et_pb_image et_pb_animation_left circular et_pb_image_2 et_always_center_on_mobile et_pb_has_overlay">
  <a href="https:/....ee/?page_id=460"><img src="https://..../wp-content/uploads/2017/00565531_813167153_o.jpg" alt="" />
    <span class="et_overlay">hello</span></a>
</div>

<div class="et_pb_module et-waypoint et_pb_image et_pb_animation_left et_pb_image_2 et_always_center_on_mobile et_pb_has_overlay">
  <a href="https:/....ee/?page_id=460"><img src="https://..../wp-content/uploads/2017/00565531_813167153_o.jpg" alt="" />
    <span class="et_overlay">hello</span></a>
</div>
```